# Multiple implicit declaration of same function in C

Tags: c, gcc, implicit-declaration

Here's my code:

```
int main(){
    printf("Hi");
    int i=10;
    printf("Hi %d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Now as C can implicitly declare a function this program will compile correctly (As it does with gcc).
But my question is, wasn't the 1st `printf` declared to return an int with 1 parameter of type `char *` ?
That makes the 2nd `printf` an error.
Yet the program compiles with no errors, just warnings (gcc). Why ?

Comment: It is not C any more as implicit declarations have been removed about 20 years ago. Remember **all functions need to be declared**

Comment: Without -pedantic gcc allows all sorts of anachronisms and extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, implicit declaration is standard violation. It is removed from the standard.

Quoting `C11`, Foreword

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> — remove implicit function declaration

That said, in earlier version of C, for a function which is considered declared implicitly (i.e., used before the compiler has knowledge about the function prototype) *was* supposed to

- return an `int`
- accepts any number and type of parameter.

So, as long as the function declaration and the definition does not collide (say, return type mismatch), you'll not get any error. However, a strictly conforming compiler MUST produce a diagnostic.

Comment: @MarkWeston As per my understanding, `C11` is the latest and thus, applicable standard. It was already removed in C99, though.

Comment: Is "implicitly declared" a function that was not declared with a prototype?

Comment: Reference to your first sentence please.

Comment: @Hritik added the quote.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Implicitly declared function is a funciton which is *called* without declaration or definition before the point in source where it is called.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `printf` is implicitly defined to be `int printf(...)`, not `int printf(char *)`, thus compiler detects no errors when you call it with different arguments.

Comment: Is "implicitly declared" a function that the compiler knows about (type and parameters)?

Comment: No - it is not.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Are you talking about C89? C99 and C11 prohibit implicit declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not portable C since you're missing the requisite `#include` which brings in the function prototype for `printf`: any sort of implicit declaration was removed in C99.

If you want to write non-portable C, then the best thing you can do is to consult your compiler documentation. In this instance it looks like your friendly compiler is defaulting to `int printf(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

gcc unfortunately has some built in notion of printf even though a header file has not been used.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    printf("%s\n");
    printf("%u\n",x);
    more_fun("%s\n");
    more_fun("%u\n",x);
    return(x+1);
}

so.c: In function ‘fun’:
so.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%s\n");
     ^
so.c:5:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
so.c:5:5: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
so.c:5:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s\n");
            ^
so.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘more_fun’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     more_fun("%s\n");
     ^
```

fortunately if we make our own it does forget at least a little.

```
void printf(char *, unsigned int );
void more_fun(char *, unsigned int );
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    printf("%s\n");
    printf("%u\n",x);
    more_fun("%s\n");
    more_fun("%u\n",x);
    return(x+1);
}

so.c:3:6: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘printf’
 void printf(char *, unsigned int );
      ^
so.c: In function ‘fun’:
so.c:7:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘printf’
     printf("%s\n");
     ^
so.c:3:6: note: declared here
 void printf(char *, unsigned int );
      ^
so.c:9:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘more_fun’
     more_fun("%s\n");
     ^
so.c:4:6: note: declared here
 void more_fun(char *, unsigned int );
      ^
```

but we are talking about one compiler, one compiler does not cover it you have to try many/all.  Standard or not a compiler could still notice your changing the use of the function and let you know about it, this compiler chooses not to.   The error here is not that the compiler didnt notice the function being used differently from one undeclared instance to another but that there was no declaration, and then it does notice the difference as one would hope.

Comment: Well that happens with strlen as well.